# Spring-data-dynamoDB in Spring Boot app: @DynamoDBTable classes not recognized as persisted entities if @EnableDynamoDBAuditing configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add support for DynamoDB to an existing Spring Boot/Spring Data JPA application - using [spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb).

- **Spring Boot** version `1.5.12.RELEASE`
- **spring-data-dynamodb** version `4.5.5`

I want to be able to switch between JPA (Oracle, HSQL) and DynamoDB using mutually exclusive Spring profiles (`jpa` and `dynamodb`.) So I have two profile-specific `@Configuration` classes:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("jpa")
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.persistence.repositories")
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaConfig {
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dynamodb")
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "my.persistence.repositories")
@EnableDynamoDBAuditing
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "amazon.aws")
@Setter
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    private String dynamoDbEndpoint;
    private String accessKey;
    private String secretKey;
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        Assert.hasText(dynamoDbEndpoint, "AWS DynamoDB endpoint is not configured!");
        Assert.hasText(region, "AWS sign-in region must be explicitly configured!");
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(amazonAWSCredentials()));
        builder.setEndpointConfiguration(
                  new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoDbEndpoint, region));
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }
}
```

}

The `Application` class is annotated with `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`.

Note that I am specifically attempting to exclude any JPA auto-configuration when the `dynamodb` profile is activated. For DynamoDB, I want to enable audit via `EnableDynamoDBAuditing` - I am assuming that it is the `spring-data-dynamodb`'s equivalent of Spring Data JPA's `EnableJpaAuditing`, although I can't find any clear documentation on it, and the Javadoc offers nothing.

I am hoping to be able to use the *same Spring Data repository interfaces and entity classes*. There is, of course, nothing in the repository interfaces that is specific to JPA or DynamoDB. And I assume that adding DynamoDb annotations to the existing JPA annotations should not hurt anything. So I have entity classes such as the following (an old JPA entity class with *added DynamoDB annotations*):

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "person")
 @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "person")
 @EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @ToString
 public class Person implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @DynamoDBHashKey
     @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
     private String id;

     @Column(name = "first_name")
     @DynamoDBAttribute
     private String firstName;

     @Column(name = "last_name")
     @DynamoDBAttribute
     private String lastName;

     @Column(name = "created_dt", nullable = false)
     @CreatedDate
     @DynamoDBAttribute
     @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
     private Date createdDate;

     ... etc.
}
```

And the corresponding repository remains unchanged (I've only added the `@EnableScan` annotation, following an example):

```
 @EnableScan
 public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, String> {

      Person findOne(String id);

      Person save(Person person);
 }
```

When I run the application with the `jpa` Spring profile activated everything works fine - just as it used to prior to the addition of the DynamoDB support. However, when I launch the application with the `dynamodb` profile, it starts up ok, but the data access operations fail with an exception that indicates that the Person object is **not recognized as a persisted entity**:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported entity my.model.Person! Could not determine IsNewStrategy.
at org.springframework.data.support.IsNewStrategyFactorySupport.getIsNewStrategy(IsNewStrategyFactorySupport.java:48) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.auditing.IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.markAudited(IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.mapping.event.AuditingEventListener.onBeforeSave(AuditingEventListener.java:44) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.mapping.event.AbstractDynamoDBEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractDynamoDBEventListener.java:109) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
```

When I step through the framework code in the debugger I see that the exception is thrown when the check for the target class being a persisted entity class returns `false`, which, in return, yields a null `IsNewStrategy`.

The stack trace indicates that this happens during the audit listener execution.

My entity classes seem to be not recognized as persisted entities by Spring Data DynamoDB - if DynamoDB audit is enabled via `@EnableDynamoDBAuditing`. If I remove that annotation from my configuration, everything seems to work fine. I need to have the ability to automatically set create/update date fields - in the same way I do that with Spring Data JPA. (In my particular case, so far, I don't care about setting "createdBy", so I don't need to set the `auditorAwareRef` property on `@EnableDynamoDBAuditing` annotation.) Is it enough to just use the `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp` annotation on the date fields? What is the purpose of `@EnableDynamoDBAuditing` then? And why do things break when the latter is present?